# Type 'void' is not assignable to type '((event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void) React TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-props, tsx

Im a beginner in React Typescript, and I have defined some props is a **.JS** file that I want to use in a **.tsx** file. but I receive this error on one of my TypeScript lines:

```
 <MyTextField style={{width:'60%'}}  name='ActivationDate' type='date' defaultValue={values1.ActivationDate} onChange={handleChange('ActivationDate')}/>
```

```
Type 'void' is not assignable to type '((event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void) | ((event: ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => void) | ((event: ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => void) | undefined'.
```

The CodeSandbox contains both my JS file and TSX file :
https://codesandbox.io/s/tsx-rj694

what seems to be the problem and how can I write this correctly?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I assume you are not passing the event object into the `handleChange` method.

This is how you should amend your `onChange` event handler:

```
onChange={() => handleChange('ActivationDate')}
```

For your information, if you need to access the event object in the `onChange` call, you will need to explicitly specify the right types.

```
onChange={handleChange}
```

And when you define the function,

```
const handleChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  // do the rest here
}
```

Comment: in my  case I also had to declare explicit type to `handleChange` variable : `const handleChange : ChangeEventHandler  = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {}`

Answer (score 10):

```
onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => handleChange(e.target.value)}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this cause unnecessary rerenders?

Answer (score 0):

```
onChange={handleChange}
```

in my case I also had to declare explicit type to handleChange variable :

```
 const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {
    // do the rest here
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).