# Type '(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, components

I am first-time using Typescript to build a project from the ZTM course, which is originally on Javascript. I have encountered an issue, where I can't set a type to the *event* parameter. It says:

```
Type '(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>'.ts(2322)
```

Here is my `onSearchChange` function, located in my **App.tsx**, which contains the *event* parameter. With this function, I expect to see console logging of an object, when typing something in the search bar.

```
onSearchChange(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
        console.log(event);
    }
```

My render method, which renders that function, is below:

```
render() {
        return (
            <div className='tc'>
                <h1>RoboFriends</h1>
                <SearchBox title='search box' searchChange={this.onSearchChange}/>
                <CardList title='list of robot cards' robots={this.state.robots} />
            </div>
        );
    }
```

`searchChange` property is marked with an error, mentioned above:

```
Type '(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>'.
```

There is my search bar component in my **SearchBox.tsx** file. It looks as follows:

```
import { FC, ChangeEvent } from 'react';

interface ISearchBoxProps {
    title: string;
    searchChange: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>;
}

const SearchBox: FC<ISearchBoxProps> = ({searchChange}) => {
    return (
        <div className='pa2'>
            <input
                className='pa3 ba b--green bg-lightest-blue'
                type='search'
                placeholder='search robots'
                onChange={searchChange}
            />
        </div>
    )
    
}

export default SearchBox;
```

The `onChange` property is marked by VSCode with errors:

```
Type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>'.
Type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>' provides no match for the signature '(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void'.
```

I tried different options, including this gentleman's advice, but I couldn't get rid of these errors:
[Type 'void' is not assignable to type '((event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void) React TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61244635/type-void-is-not-assignable-to-type-event-changeeventhtmlinputelement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with your interface

```
interface ISearchBoxProps{
 title: string;
 searchChange: (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)=>void
}
```

Comment: @Lars Vonk,

 thanks to both of you. This answer has worked out my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You define `searchChange` as an `Event` I think in your code what you meant to do is define `searchChange` as a method that accept `event: ChangeEvent<...>` as an argument. This means you have to change the `ISearchBoxProps` interface to have the type `(event: ChangeEvent<...>) => void` for prop `searchChange`.